# Remove all objects from json data which contains a specific keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm just looking for the best practice to remove remove all objects from json data which contains a specific term/keyword.

my json data looks like this

```
json = [{
 "name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "cars":"BMW"
},
{
 "name":"Micheal",
 "age":30,
 "cars":"Ford,BMW"
},
{
 "name":"Andy",
 "age":29,
 "cars":"Ford"
},
{
 "name":"Andy",
 "age":29,
 "cars":"Ford,Toyota"
}];
```

I want to remove the objects which has the keyword "BMW".

Comment: `Array.filter()`. sidenote: you have a javascript object, it's only JSON when it's a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `Array.filter()`:

```js
var arr = [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "cars":"BMW" }, { "name":"Micheal", "age":30, "cars":"Ford,BMW" }, { "name":"Andy", "age":29, "cars":"Ford" }, { "name":"Andy", "age":29, "cars":"Ford,Toyota" }];

var result = arr.filter(({cars})=> !cars.includes("BMW"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. :)

Comment: @ArunKarthickK happy to help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

For **removing element from array of objects based containing string** `Array.filter` is best solution but its another **alternative** can be `Array.reduce` as below:

```js
var arr =[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "cars":"BMW" }, { "name":"Micheal", "age":30, "cars":"Ford,BMW" }, { "name":"Andy", "age":29, "cars":"Ford" }, { "name":"Andy", "age":29, "cars":"Ford,Toyota" }];

var newarr = arr.reduce((acc, elem) => !elem.cars.includes("BMW") ? acc.concat(elem) : acc, []);

console.log(newarr);
```